# Mouse coordinates are relative to JFrame and not my world map

Tags: java, mouselistener

I have developed a game that has a map made of tiles. I added a camera that follows the player using Graphics2D.translate. I also have a MouseListener implemented in a Listener class.

I made so that the game prints the mouse coordinates to the console, **however** here is when I get the issue I want to solve. The MouseListener's coordinates seem to be **relative** to the Java Window. I however have a map that is larger than the Java window. How do I make the MouseListener adapt to my world size?

I hope this description is good enough. If you need more information just ask and I will provide that information.

Thanks, all help is appreciated

Comment: You don't make the MouseListener adapt.  You keep track of the map coordinates you're displaying and transform the window coordinates to map coordinates.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would transform the screen cords to world cords please?

Comment: Sure.  If the upper left-hand corner of your map display is actual map coordinate [200, 100], you add 200 to the x value from the MouseListener and add 100 to the y value from the MouseListener.

Comment: I think I understand but how is this related to transforming?

Comment: I got the problem solved, I used the Cameras translate to get the upper left corner and it works flawlessly! Thanks for the help, how will I be able to give you the "Best answer" as you wrote it as a comment?